# What is Debug mode and Release mode in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I am new to OpenCV,I need to know the difference between the Debug mode and Release mode in OpenCV.

I am using Opencv in Linux platform (Ubuntu 14.04 and Debian 7.6),and Cmake 2.8. for build.

I just use the cmake command got from internet for building the OpenCV libraries I don't know whether it is in Debug or Release mode? how to check the mode?

How to enable and disable Debug and Release mode?

Will be there any difference in the output ,if I build the same code in these modes ?

Comment: opencv prebuilt debug libraries have a letter `d` before `.lib` and `.dll`

Answer (score 2):

The differences are explained in : http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

> The Debug has many features that exist so you can find and resolve
>   easier bugs inside your application. In contrast the Release is an
>   optimized version, where the goal is to make the application run as
>   fast as possible or to be as small as possible.

Basically, the output will be different in performance, since said debugging features are trimmed out. You can set debug/release mode when you build your application :

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

where `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release\Debug`

Comment: That is not helpful